# Unable to establish communication with google cloud sql instance using proxy

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio, cloud-sql-proxy

I am trying to connect to my CloudSql Instance using `cloudsql-proxy`.

```
        - name: cloudsql-proxy
          command:
            - /cloud_sql_proxy
            - -instances=$(project):europe-west2:$(DB_INSTANCE_NAME)=tcp:5432
            - -credential_file=/etc/secrets/google_credentials.json
          image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.13
```

I am getting the following error:

```
-> Throttling refreshCfg(project:europe-west2:db): it was only called 1.006390387s ago
-> couldn't connect to "project:europe-west2:db": Post https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/project/instances/db/createEphemeral?alt=json&prettyPrint=false: oauth2: cannot fetch token: Post https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token: read tcp 10.x.xx.4:59004->216.xx.xxx.202:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

The error message is so confusing that I could not get if it is a network issue or permissions issue. I have checked the key and secrets are mounted properly and same configuration.
I have tried to see if it is a problem with Istio connection and created service entries

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: google-apis
spec:
  hosts:
    - "www.googleapis.com"
  addresses:
    - 216.xx.xx.202
  ports:
    - name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    - name: tcp
      number: 5432
      protocol: TCP
    - name: sql
      number: 3307
      protocol: TCP
  resolution: DNS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: cloudsql-instances
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*.googleapis.com"
    - "gkeconnect.googleapis.com"
    - "oauth2.googleapis.com"
  addresses:
    - 172.xx.xx.xx
    - 
  ports:
    - name: tcp
      number: 5432
      protocol: TCP
    - name: sql
      number: 3307
      protocol: TCP
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
```

**Note**:

1. GKE Clusters is created using terraform-google-module with egress and and ingress enabled
2. Both GKE cluster and Cloud SQL instance are private

On a similar note , I have a query -> can we connect to cloudsql instance which is already serving a different GKE cluster(This question may sound foolish, but I can't think of anything else).

Comment: Seems to be a auth error... but the weird part is: you said cloudsql and gke is private, but the error point to `216.xx.xxx.202:443`... The GKE cluster has the correct permission to access CloudSQL?

Comment: yes, Scopes are set as "cloud-platform" and the service account that is being has sql client permissions.

Comment: Both are in the same network, subnetwork? Have you checked the firewall rules?